# Python condition threading object to allow many readers but one writer

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements, locking

I got this code from the Python Cookbook I believe

The `acquire_read` method says it blocks only if a thread has acquired a lock

I dont see how as wouldnt the acquire_read method still block other readers when it calls

`self._read_ready.acquire()` which the method
`acquire_write` also calls?

```
import threading
class ReadriteLock:

    """ 
    A lock object that allows many simultaneous "read locks", but
    only one "write lock." 
    """    
    def __init__(self):
        self._read_ready = threading.Condition(threading.Lock())
        self._readers = 0

    def acquire_read(self):
        """ 
        Acquire a read lock. Blocks only if a thread has
        acquired the write lock. 
        """
        self._read_ready.acquire()
        try:
            self._readers += 1
        finally:
            self._read_ready.release()

    def release_read(self):
        """ 
        Release a read lock. 
        """
        self._read_ready.acquire()
        try:
            self._readers -= 1
            if not self._readers:
                self._read_ready.notifyAll()
        finally:
            self._read_ready.release()

    def acquire_write(self):
        """ 
        Acquire a write lock. Blocks until there are no
        acquired read or write locks. 
        """
        self._read_ready.acquire()
        while self._readers > 0:
            self._read_ready.wait()

    def release_write(self):
        """ Release a write lock. """
        self._read_ready.release()
```

Comment: hello, what would you like to achieve with the code?

Comment: To have multiples readers but only one write

Comment: Such design will not work, since when you enter lock, the whole thread is blocked until lock is released. So you can't read and write in the same threads, you need to separate writing Thread and reading Threads. I guess you're looking for "one producer and several consumer" pattern, or "several producers, several consumers" pattern, am I right?